# Not work ngx-dropdown in Mozilla Firefox (In Chrome work well)

Tags: angular, firefox, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I've this html code in my **angular 6** template (use **ngx-bootstrap**)

```
 <div class="pull-left" class="btn-group" dropdown>
     <span dropdownToggle (click)="false" class="fa fa-file menu-toggle team2-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></span>
     <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="file.xlsx">Import in Excel</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

In Google Chrome, the dropdown works well. But in Mozilla Firefox a dropdown is not working.

```
angular version: 6.0.1

ngx-bootstrap: 3.0.1
```